# Angularjs undefined variable in controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, undefined, angularjs-controller, angularjs-factory

I have a problem in controller with the properties of object. My factory return one object with another object and one function. I can call the function but i can't access in another object properties. Here is my code:

**My factory**

```
app.factory('User', function () {

var User = {};

User.get = function () {
   // Call the service... done
   User.data = response.data;        
};

return User;
});
```

**My controller**

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, User) {
$scope.user = User;

console.log(user);  // print correct one object with 
                       the function get and data object with user data

console.log(user.data); // undefined

});
```

Thanks, and sorry for my english disaster

Comment: You don't actually get() data

Comment: i can call get() function, but i can't access to $scope.user.data

Comment: Field 'User.data' intialized only in User.get() call, and you haven't called it.

Comment: Aside from not actually calling `get()` (which is the only place where you're actually defining `.data`), you're probably making [this mistake](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron).

Comment: You can call it, but there is no such call in your code snippet. User.get() never executes

Comment: And you console log user, while you should use $scope.user within the controller (or User if you intend to log the service). Ofcourse it's undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is my error, i call in another controller User.get();, My problem is in time

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, User) {
   $scope.user = User;

   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(user.data); // i have data
   }, 5000);


});
```

Comment: You're problem isn't solved with `setTimeout`.  You need to use the `$promise` methodology.  In your example code, `setTimeout` would break if it took more than 5 seconds to return the data from your AJAX call

Comment: Thanks @LloydBanks i make a callback when getUser service responded, and then i call the init function of my controller.

Answer (score 0):

```js
app.factory('User', function () {

var User = {};
  
  User.data=null;

User.get = function () {
   // Call the service... done
   User.data = response.data;        
};

return User;
});
```

Controller:

```js
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, User) {
$scope.user = User;

console.log(user);

console.log(user.data); // null,because you did not call the method User.get();
  
  User.get();

  
console.log(user.data); // this will print the response data which you assign in the User.get() method
});
```

In the code you given, User.data will give the object but before you have to call `User.get()` function.

Sorry for my English .....

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems. The way you set up your factory is hurting you. So I would return the whole factory so you have that function. You don't have to define User inside the factory because it is the name of the factory (therefore it is an object)

```
app.factory('User', function () {

return {
    get: function() {
        //return API call
    };
});
```

Next, you are defining $scope.user and then calling user. You never defined user, just $scope.user. Also, you must call the get function in user to return data. And it will not be

```
app.controller('Controller', function ($scope, User) {
$scope.user = User.get();

console.log($scope.user);  // This will be the data

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `settimeout` will not auto fire the `$digest` and the 2 way data binding may not aware of the update.

1. user q and promise instead of timeout
2. if timeout is required, use $timeout instead of settimeout.

Comment: Thanks, i use timeout native javascript only for a testing, i solved my problem with promise $q